# CSS @Media Print adjust element (image) in #slider

Tags: css, printing, slider, background-image

Trying to adjust the #slider content (an image) in @media print so that the center of the image in the slider will be visible and centered in 300px height.

Figured out how to adjust the slider itself but can't figure out the content/element/image NAME to target within the slider [tried #slides, #background-image, #content, #flex-slider, etc --> yet nothing will move the image within the slider]

so far I've added:

```
@media print 
    {#slider {
height: 300px !important;
}
```

The attached image is an example of what we'd like the physical paper print out to look like.

Thank you for any help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh1dy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its about your slider css :

```
#slider .slides > li, #slider .flex-viewport, #slider .slides { min-height: 300px; }
```

adjust this element.